# What is <main+x> in gdb output?

Tags: c, linux, gdb

What is `<main+8>` saying here?
I'm working on a book and I don't think I've missed it. I've looked online but haven't found an answer...

```
(gdb) i r $rip
rip            0x5555555546b2    
0x5555555546b2 <main+8>
```

Comment: `rip` uses 8 bytes on the `main` stack?

Answer (score 5):

the debugger prints the raw address, then tries to print the symbol associated to this address (when symbol table is available)

If it doesn't find one, it goes back to the closest known symbol, which occurs to be `main` here, and adds the actual offset. Helpful most of the time, since the address often relates to the quoted symbol (often seen in branch addresses).

Comment: This answer does not actually say what `<main+x>` is. It talks about symbols and the debugger finding the closest symbol and adding an offset, but it does not say that `<main+x>` means x bytes beyond the symbol `main`, and that that location, 8 bytes beyond `main` in this case, is equal to the value it is printed next to.